# Live Preview Iframe

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, iframe

I am building a site in node.js that allows users to have a custom page that can be edited in a dashboard. I would like this dashboard to have a live preview (similar to the way Shopify does it) in an iframe, where every time the user makes changes, the preview updates with their changes (i.e. background image or header text). The options are saved in the users document in my mongodb database, and rendered via Liquid. What is the best approach to achieve this? Should I store their options in a temporary json file? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't build it entirely on Node.js

I would rather use the power of the modern client-side Javascript and move some logic there with persisting some of the data coming from the server. This way I can lower the number of requests and make my script more flexible.

Two libraries can help in these tasks:

- Socket.io for fast communication between Node.js and the browser.
- PouchDB for client-side data storage and CRUD operations.